# Css не видит класс HTML

Tags: html, css

Html:

```css
.box {
  width: 200;
  height: 200;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium iure architecto nulla officiis ducimus earum distinctio soluta, culpa, aliquid nemo itaque perspiciatis numquam quo unde? Nulla ex hic magnam harum? </p>
</div>
```

Comment: link на css файл есть.

Comment: Всё равно не работает.

Comment: Я не исправлял код в вопросе, а просто привел его в порядок. Ответ - в ответе.

Comment: А в чем различие ?

Comment: всё понял, был не прав.

Comment: Очень хорошо. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium iure architecto nulla officiis ducimus earum distinctio soluta, culpa, aliquid nemo itaque perspiciatis numquam quo unde? Nulla ex hic magnam harum? </p>
</div>
```